# Material Design Drawer is in background how can i change that?

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

SO i have got a drawer

```
    <materialDesign:DrawerHost Margin="0" Height="350" Width="525"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignDivider}">
        <materialDesign:DrawerHost.LeftDrawerContent>
            <StackPanel Margin="16"
                        Height="23"
>
                <TextBlock Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center">LEFT FIELD</TextBlock>
                <Button Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DrawerHost.CloseDrawerCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{x:Static Dock.Left}"
                        Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}">
                    CLOSE THIS
                </Button>
                <Button Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DrawerHost.CloseDrawerCommand}"
                        Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}">
                    CLOSE ALL
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </materialDesign:DrawerHost.LeftDrawerContent>
        <Grid>
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Button Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DrawerHost.OpenDrawerCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{x:Static Dock.Left}"
                        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Margin="4">
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ArrowLeft" />
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </materialDesign:DrawerHost>
```

and I have got a Button

```
<Button>
Test Button
</Button>
```

Everything is in an

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost
```

In that Dialoghost there is a Grid in which i put my Drawer host
And when i press the Button the Drawer opens but the Button that is in the Dialoghost grid is in the foreground and the Drawer in the background how do i get the Drawer to open over the Button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy answer. The Drawer is in an Drawerhost the Drawer host just needs a Panel.ZIndex of 1. Than the Drawer is in the foreground and not the buttons